# WPF Binding button within tab control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, tabcontrol, datatrigger

I have a TabControl, and on the second tab is a button:

```
<Button Name="deleteResourceBtn">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=loadChartResourceListView}" Value="-1">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
    <Image ToolTip="Delete Resource" Source="pack://application:,,,/...namespace omitted;component/Graphics/deleteBtn.png" Style="ButtonImageStyle" />
</Button>
```

I'm binding to a list control named loadChartResourceListView... the error I'm receiving is:

> 'XamlParseException Set property
>   'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style'
>   threw an exception.' Line number '221'
>   and line position '39'.

line 221 is `</Style>`  ... not really seeing an issue with my binding, unless the TabControl hasn't loaded the second tab? Does a TabControl load tabs "on demand" ? Parhaps the second tab hasn't loaded and its trying to bind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the `InnerException` you'll see that you have an `ArgumentException` saying

> 'ButtonImageStyle' is not a valid
>   value for property 'Style'.

So I believe the error is coming from the `Image` style

Try changing `Style="ButtonImageStyle"` to `Style="{StaticResource ButtonImageStyle}"`